# LightSwitch-like RAD for Go, Ruby, Dart or Elixir (Linux)

Tags: linux, rad

[LightSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/lightswitch.aspx)-like RAD for [Go](http://golang.org), [Ruby](http://ruby-lang.org), [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) or [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/) back-end that could run under Linux (if possible with [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org)), I have found some but using different back-end programming language or doesn't run under Linux:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuBuilder (PHP, MySQL)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenXava (Java)
- https://github.com/evoluteur/evolutility (no-back-end)
- http://www.crossui.com/ (?)
- http://en.limbas.org/wiki/Main_Page (PHP)
- http://www.morfik.com/ (Windows)
- http://portofino.manydesigns.com/en (Groovy)
- http://www.wakanda.org/ (Javascript)
- http://aribaweb.org/ (Java)
- http://www.wavemaker.com/ (Java)
- http://bigprof.com/appgini/ (PHP)